# how to remove rows and count it in same file opening

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open CSV file and remove some rows from it according to given list, on same progress I want to count those rows for future usage.

Each file opening works great on separately, how can I combine them on same open file progress?

My current code is :

```
# read latest file and count rows  

with open(fileslst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in csvReader:
    for alert in alertsCode:
        if any(alert in row[11] for s in alertsCode) :
            counter=counter+1
print (str(counter)+" unnecessary codes in this file")


#open and modify the latest file

with open(fileslst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    clean_rows = [row for row in csvReader if not any(alert in row[11] for alert in alertsCode)]

with open(fileslst[-1], 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerows(clean_rows)
```

When I run it on same script it's not working but run separately will.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: when i run open file for counter - it is work, when i open file for delete rows, it is work...but, when i run both on same script it is not!

Comment: What does the script do instead of working?

Answer (score 0):

according to your initial description of the problem this could be one solution, although it can surely be optimized

```
excluded = ['your excluded list here']
deleted_rows = 0
with open(file) as read:
    with open(file2) as write:
        w = csv.writer(write)
        r = csv.reader(read)
        for row in r:
            if row not in excluded:
                w.writerow(row)
            else:
                deleted_rows += 1
```

Comment: but i need to do it on same file... 
i get this error : "IOError: File not open for writing"

Comment: is it not an option for you to delete the original file and replace it with the newly generated file afterwards? afaik the way you are supposed to parse csv files in python is to have input and output file. Nothing prevents you from deleting the input file and replacing it.

Comment: That way you are making changes to the file you are reading, so you would have to seek back to the row you want, as the file is changing. It's way more simple to just use a temporary file and then replace the original afterwards. Replacing data is easy, appending data to file is easy but as far as i know adding or removing data is usually done via temporary files.

Comment: no i dont ask for fun...in the first question i asked about delete entire row, and the answer there helped me a lot but in the current one i want to understand why 2 file opening one after another dont work as it should? 
anyway thanks for your help i did it with another solution with temp txt file just to hold the value i need.